# Add keypress or eventlistener to input, "TypeError: ...addEventListener is not a function"

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, keypress, addeventlistener

I'm working on a form where I do not want enter/return to submit the form so I used a function like this.

```
    $('[name="form"]').keypress(function(e) {
        var charCode = e.charcode || e.keyCode || e.which;
        if (charCode === 13) {
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
    });
```

That works, but now I want to assign the enter/return to perform functions on two inputs on the form. I'm totally stuck.

To get the inputs I've tried vanilla js calling by id, jQ calling by id and then a mixer of the two with variables. I've also tried .keypress, .keydown, .keyup instead of the attachEventListener method. No matter what I do, I get this error in console.

"TypeError: ...addEventListener is not a function" (or keypress, keydown etc.)

I've also researched a good deal but can't find any solution. I appreciate any suggestions.
Here is this block of code in it's current form that's giving the trouble.

```
    var yelpInput = $('#inputURL');
    var googleInput = $('#googleURL');

    yelpInput.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode === 13 ) {                        
            alert('do stuff!');
        }
    });

    // Google
    googleInput.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode === 13 ) {    
            alert('do stuff!');
        }
    });
```

Thanks

Comment: `yelpInput` and `googleInput` are jquery objects not dom objects.

Comment: I also tried grabbing the inputs by document.getElementById('yelpInput'); etc. and got the same error.

Comment: Strange. This seems to work:

https://jsfiddle.net/subterrane/0rkgdd4w/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var yelpInput = $('#inputURL');
var googleInput = $('#googleURL');

yelpInput.keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 13 ) {                        
        alert('do stuff!');
    }
});

// Google
googleInput.keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 13 ) {    
        alert('do stuff!');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I used the keydown method before and it didn't work. I must have screwed something up, because that's working now.

Answer (score 2):

`yelpInput` is `jQuery` wrapped object which does not have `addEventListener` method.

Use [`.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to attach `event-handler` on `jQuery` wrapped object or `yelpInput[0].addEventListener`/`yelpInput.get(0).addEventListener` to attach event using `JavaScript` as `yelpInput[0]` will be an `DOMElement` not `jQuery-wrapped` object.

```js
var yelpInput = $('#inputURL');
var googleInput = $('#googleURL');

yelpInput.on("keydown", function(e) {
  //-----^^^
  if (e.keyCode === 13) {
    alert('do stuff!');
  }
});
googleInput.on("keydown", function(e) {
  //-------^^^
  if (e.keyCode === 13) {
    alert('do stuff!');
  }
});
```